# jQuery Mobile Listview with textview inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I've looked through the [docs for listview](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-pre/docs/lists/lists-search.html), however there are no examples of a textview placed inside of a listview cell. I'm fairly new to jQuery Mobile and Javascript in general, so I'm wondering if it's even possible to do this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you will find your answer right here

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-pre/docs/lists/lists-forms-inset.html

Should be straightforward.